# wxpython - Erase background erases non-background components

Tags: python, wxpython

In wxpython, I want to have a window with a picture that changes based on use of toolbar buttons with text controls on top of the picture. When I click the toolbar buttons, I am posting an erase background event, then capturing the erase event, and redrawing the new background from there (base on [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/)).

Mostly works well, except that the text controls cease to be drawn once I redraw the background. They're still there, just not drawn.

Here is a simplified code that demonstrates the problem. If you run this code and click the button to toggle drawing the background image or not, the text controls disappear.:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class PanelWithDrawing(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PanelWithDrawing, self).__init__(parent, size=(100, 40))

        self.showbmp = False

        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(10, 10))

    def onErase(self, dc):
        if self.showbmp:
            # dc.DrawBitmap(wx.Bitmap('background.png', 0, 0)
            dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 40, 40)   # use a drawing instead so you don't have to find a png

class Toolbar(wx.ToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(parent, -1)

        self.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_SAVE, "Record", wx.Bitmap("picture.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), wx.NullBitmap, wx.ITEM_NORMAL, "", "")

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.toolbar = Toolbar(self)
        self.SetToolBar(self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.Realize()

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.panel1 = PanelWithDrawing(self.panel)
        vbox.Add(self.panel1)

        # self.panel2 = PanelWithText(self.panel)
        # vbox.Add(self.panel2)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        self.toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onButton)
        self.panel1.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.onErase)

    def onErase(self, evt):
        try:
            dc = evt.GetDC()
        except:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        self.panel1.onErase(dc)

    def onButton(self, evt):
        self.panel1.showbmp = not self.panel1.showbmp
        wx.PostEvent(self.panel1, wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Example')
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()   # use this for debugging GUI design
    app.MainLoop()
```

How do I tell wxpython to draw all the non-background stuff again? Alternatively, how do I not un-draw it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

After working on it for a few days, I got it! And the answer is trivially simple (as usual).

`wx.PostEvent(self.panel1, wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND))` should be replaced with `self.Refresh()` to refresh the whole frame and not just force a specific (and apparently unsafe) redraw.